# How to send a SOAP API call in java and return it in json

Tags: java, json, api, post, soap

I'm trying to send an api call and then read the returned json and print a value in the json information that is returned. The curl looks like this:

```
curl "https://(address goes here)?where=eq(open,true)&fields=name,totals" \ 
-H 'Api-Key: (api key here)'
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Caller {

public void APICall(String str) throws Exception
{
    String url = "(address)" + str + 
    "(address continued)";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestProperty("Api-Key",  
    "(API Key)";
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

    OutputStreamWriter out = new 
    OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    out.write(data);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    String inputLine;

     StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
     while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
     }
    in.close();
    out.close();



}

}
```

And then I call it from another class like this:

```
           try {
           call.APICall(codeArray.get(x));
            } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
           }
```

str is the inputed API code for this address, and codeArray.get(x) is stored API codes. I'm not sure how to add the parameters in the curl code or return it in json format. I have hidden the address and API Key.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to explain more about the SOAP payload you send and the answer received, and how is the JSON you expect to return, but I'm going to guess what you are trying to ask and try to answer it.

I can see in the code that you send a JSON to the API call, so I assume that a client will consume your endpoint with SOAP. The API you call should return a JSON right? Your endpoint will return a SOAP XML answer (or should it be raw JSON?), so you must do a conversion from JSON to XML (SOAP).

***If you want to return a JSON to client and send a SOAP XML payload then read the following paragraph.***

You may be wanting to instead return a XML, return a JSON, to do this, if you are using a framework either on the server side or client side, you must read the documentation. If it is possible to change the headers (server side) through the framework you should accept the XML format (`Accept: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8`) and send to your client `Content-type: application/json`. In your client, when you send the request, you must have the headers of `Content-type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8` and `Accept: application/json`.

TL;DR; (For client sending XML and receiving JSON)

**Server:**

```
Accept: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-type: application/json
```

**Client:**

```
Accept: application/json
Content-type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
```

**Resources:**

[Header Field Definitions](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

[SOAP Headers HTTP](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_soap.asp)